# Grafana OAuth with Keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, grafana

I am using helm charts. During the deploy process, I override values as below:

```yaml
auth.generic_oauth:  # for SSO
      groups_attribute_path: contains(groups[*], 'GrafanaAdmins') && 'Admin' || 'Viewer'
      enabled: true
      name: Keycloak
      allow_sign_up: false
      client_id: grafana
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
      scopes: openid,email,profile,groups
      team_ids:
      allowed_organizations:
      auth_url: AUTH_URL
      token_url: TOKEN_URL
      api_url: API_URL
      tls_skip_verify_insecure: true
```

In the Keycloke, I create a client, a client scope, a group mapper in the client scope, a group and assign GrafanaAdmins group to a user.

**What I want to achieve** is to be able to login to Grafana with a user defined in Keycloak that is also assigned the GrafanaAdmins group.

**What I have** is this error:

```sh
t=2021-12-27T13:32:18+0000 lvl=warn msg="Not allowing oauth_generic_oauth login, user not found in internal user database and allow signup = false"
t=2021-12-27T13:32:18+0000 lvl=eror msg="invalid username or password" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname=
```

I don't want to sign up new users nor I want to use additional database. It should use Keycloak.

Grafana documentation is not very descriptive and it is hard to get around it.

Comment: Do you use Grafana Enterprise 8.1+ version with valid licence?

Comment: I use this [Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana) in a Helm chart, app version 7.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. [Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/#groups-mapping) is clear:

> Groups mapping: Available in Grafana Enterprise v8.1 and later versions.

You are using Grafana 7.1.5 and I guess also free OSS Grafana (not a paid enterprise version, where license is required), so *group mapping* (config `groups_attribute_path`) is not possible in your case.

2. You are mixing also Grafana role mapping (`role_attribute_path`) with Grafana group mapping (`groups_attribute_path`) Please note `role != group`. So I guess you wanted:

```
role_attribute_path: contains(groups[*], 'GrafanaAdmins') && 'Admin' || 'Viewer'
```

instead of:

```
groups_attribute_path: contains(groups[*], 'GrafanaAdmins') && 'Admin' || 'Viewer'
```

3. Grafana creates internal users, based on the OIDC response, so you want to sign up new users in `auth.generic_oauth` section:

```
allow_sign_up: true
```

4. I bet your `scopes` config has wrong syntax and it should be:

```
scopes: openid email profile groups
```

Generally, you are using `groups` in the Keycloak to map `roles` in the Grafana. It is possible, but better logic will be to use `roles` in the Keycloak to map `roles` in the Grafana. Keycloak/Grafana have concept roles/groups and it is up to you how will you use them for your users. I would start with basic `roles` concept first.